# ExponentialSmoothing - forecast daily data

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, holtwinters

I have a file with 5 years worth of daily data from 2015 to 2019 (31/12/2019) and I need to forecast daily values for 2021;
I use statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing and until now I was able to forecast it by also forecasting year 2019 and 2020.
Is it possible to forecast 2021 without doing it for 2020?

Here's what I have in terms of code:

```
fit1 = ExponentialSmoothing(train[colval],seasonal_periods=730,trend=trend, seasonal=seasonal,).fit()
prediction_result = fit1.forecast(365)
```

With the above code, the forecast also starts just after the training data set, is it normal?

This is how I split my data: 2015-2018 train and 2019 for test

Comment: You can check [predict](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing.predict.html#statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing.predict). You can pass the start date and end date to predict. However you need your series to have datetimeindex with freq variable defined

Comment: @max12525k from what i have tested, start date must match an existing index from the dataset and the one i have does not contain any 2021 dates. should i fill it with dates but no values maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use predict function to forecast for any date if you feed the `datetimeindex` based series to `ExponentialSmoothing` while training which has frequency set. AirPassengers data has frequency set to Month start. The data contained in AirPassengers is for 1949 - 1960.

Please refer below example for details:

```py
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('AirPassengers.csv')
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'])
df = df.set_index('Month')
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing
es = ExponentialSmoothing(df).fit()
es.predict('2021-05-01', '2021-08-01')
```

you will have the output as follows:

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | 431.792 |
| 2021-06-01 00:00:00 | 431.792 |
| 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | 431.792 |
| 2021-08-01 00:00:00 | 431.792 |

I hope this answers your question.